# Regex string retrieval in python

Tags: python, regex, string

How to parse this regex in python?

Here I need to parse the string "**Miracle workers**" between "From" and "date time stamp"
in the efficient way.

```
    s = """
      business hours. Keyword Search: Sales, Operations, Director, Medical, Medical Devices, DME, Respiratory Equipment, Sales Rep, Account Executive, Exec, Business... <br />
             From Miracle Workers - 26 Apr 2012 08:45:15 GMT
          -  View all <a href="http://www.indeed.com/l-Houston,-TX-jobs.html">Houston    jobs</a>
    """
```

This is the regex i am doing.I need to get the efficient regex.

```
    regex1 = re.findall('From\ ([A-Za-z\ ]+)\-',s)
     ['Miracle Workers ']
```

Extracting another string from url.

```
  s2 = http://www.indeed.com/job/Region-Manager-Field-Sales-at-Covidien-in-Atlanta,-GA-a1a421aabb4d54a7"
  regex2 = re.findall('-in-([A-Za-z-]+),-([A-Z]{2})',str(job.url))[0]
```

Here i am getting two tuples like **('Atlanta', 'GA')** instead of that Need to get "**Atlanta,GA"**

How it supposed to do to get the results in effective way in all circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

Using () your are grouping results, this way, findall give you a tuple. Try this regexp (without grouping):

```
regexp = '-in-[A-Za-z-]+,-[A-Z]{2}'
```

Comment: '-in-Atlanta,-GA'  output is getting like that.fine.Is it fine my regex for the first string?Will it work for all circumstances?

Comment: That string will be always in english? In that case I think so, but better than [A-Za-z\ ], use [A-Za-z\s]+ or at least [A-Za-z\ \t], or [\w\ \t]+ (it depends on the expected input)